# Unicode regex does not work in clojure

Tags: regex, clojure

I have the following string I'd like to match:

```
"Ambrosia,Restore Health, , , "
```

containing unicode whitespace (don't ask me why). `/,\s*,/u` works just fine in regex101.

But `#"(?u),\s*,"` does not work in clojure:

```
(re-find #"(?u),\s*," "Ambrosia,Restore Health, , , ") ;nil, should be , ,
```

Why does this fail?

Comment: This returns `", ,"` for me.

Comment: I believe `\s` matches six ASCII characters and those six ASCII characters only. See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef).

Comment: @TimPote believe that its a limitation of copy-pasting into the browser, copying it back over works but the original string still fails

Comment: @glts that nailed it, copy pasting the horizontal whitespace grouping got it (clojure doesn't appear to support the `\h` shorthand). Put it in an answer and I'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe `\s` matches six ASCII characters and those six ASCII characters only: see [the documentation for `Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef).

As you found out already, it may be worth trying some of the other whitespace character classes like `\h` or `\v`.

Also, the `\p{...}` construct can do actual Unicode property matching. `White_Space` seems the most promising.